# How can I populate a query that contains multiple search results?

Tags: mongoose

I am attempting to perform a query that grabs a list of users and populates one of the fields for all users that are grabbed in the query. For some reason I can't get it to work. However, if I remove the `populate` line in the query, then I get my results, but without the populated field. Here is what I have:

```
var contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    title: String,
    company: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Company'
    },
    favorite: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Favorite'
    }
});

contactSchema.methods.getAllContacts = function(company_id, cb) {
    return this.model('Contact')
      .find({company: company_id})
      .populate('favorite') // my query is successful if I leave out this line
      .sort({name: 'asc'})
      .exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('ERROR = ' + err);
          cb(null, false);
        } else {
          cb(null, data);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error when leaving the `populate` call in?

Comment: I get this error when I include the ``populate`` call: 'ERROR = CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id"'

Comment: That means you've got a `favorite` field in one or more of your docs that contains an empty string. That can't be converted to an ObjectId, thus the error.  To fix this you should remove those ref fields with empty strings using an `update` with `$unset`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved modifying the populate statement:

```
.populate({
    path: 'favorite',
    match: { _id: {$not: {$size: 0}}}
})
```

As suggested in the comment above, this handles the case where one of the documents contains an empty string.